# Will installing a second SQL Instance cause an outage on existing instances?

Tags: sql-server

Like the title says, I just want to verify if we have the need to install a secondary SQL instance on a server that already has one SQL Instance, will the installation of the secondary instance cause an outage on the first?

Comment: Is that actually a good idea, or will these two instances fight over resources and both perform badly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may require to restart before the install to pass prerequisites or after the install to complete the installation.
You should be prepared to reboot the server.

Comment: Agreed. This is one of those "Do you feel lucky?" moments. :-)

Comment: And note that you should always try to reboot after installing software as a test for the _next_ time you reboot.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - oh yes! An oft forgotten point! (Oft forgotten by me, anyway ... usually recognized only when it bites me days or weeks later ...)

Answer (score 2):

> will the installation of the secondary instance cause an outage on the first?

I interpret your question as will running 2nd instance installation cause outage or affect services of already installed instance. If this is what you are asking then no, it will not but it would be advisable to run any new installation during non production hours. If you are asking about installation popping for restart then yes it may be as Fernando suggested.